# How to create a hyperlink to an API that requires a Request Header in Java Spring?

Tags: java

I have a Reporting requirement where a user submits a batch job. Once the job is done they will get an email in their inbox with a hyperlink to download the generated report.

Now there is an additional requirement to capture the USER as a header on the REST API. If we require our user to login to our UI to download the file we are getting this value, but is there anyway that I can capture the value while still supporting the hyperlink from the users email for convenience.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/file/download/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "USER", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Downloads a Generated Report",
                  notes = "Downloads a Generated Report by name.",
                  response = Resource.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid Input"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")})
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(
            @PathVariable String filename,
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse){

        if(!GenericValidator.isValidFilename(filename)){
            throw new BadRequestException(String.format("Invalid Filename: %s", filename));
        }
        Resource file;
        if((file = reportService.download(filename)) == null){
            return null;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename()  + "\"")
                .body(file);
    }
```

Comment: Use `required=false` in the `@ApiImplicitParam` annotation?

Comment: If I do that the hyperlink works, but I get NULL for the USER value. I'm asking if there is anyway to capture the USER value from the hyperlink directly or implicitly. - I am generating the hyperlink and know the USER at that time.

Comment: Because you are generating the hyperlink, you can just put the username in the url, no? 'https://www.server.com/file/download/filename.doc?user=tony' and add a '@RequestParam'

Comment: Yeah I guess I could capture the param as a request param instead of as a header..